# grouping resultset - mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following sql which returns the total number of books grouped by status

```
    select COUNT(BOOK_ID) AS book_num, BOOK_STATUS_FK from BOOKS group by BOOK_STATUS_FK;

+---------+------------------+
| book_num | BOOK_STATUS_FK |
+---------+------------------+
|      57 |                2 |
|     162 |                3 |
|    9736 |                4 |
|     104 |                5 |
|      29 |               22 |
|       1 |               23 |
|       5 |               25 |
|      14 |               54 |
+---------+------------------+
```

I would like to group the resultset into 2 rows only where one row represents the number of books with BOOK_STATUS_FK > 4 and the 2nd to represent the number of books with BOOK_STATUS_FK <= 4

Is there a way of doing that in sql?

Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/) See [ask advice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask-advice), please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 2 row solution Gordon Linoff suggests wont produce 2 rows when one of the counts is 0.

The following will give both counts in a single row:

```
select ifnull( sum( if( book_status_fk > 4, 1, 0 ) ), 0), ifnull( sum( if( book_status_fk <= 4, 1, 0 ) ), 0 )
from books
```

Edit: added ifnull's

Answer (score 2):

This is an aggregation with a case statement:

```
select (case when book_tatus_fk > 4 then '>4' else '<=4' end) as grp, count(*)
from books
group by (case when book_tatus_fk > 4 then '>4' else '<=4' end)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you always need two rows, even if count of a group is 0, you can use palindrom's solution or you can use this slightly modified version of Gordon Linoff's query:

```
select grp.g, count(BOOK_STATUS_FK)
from
  (select '<=4' g union all select '>4') grp left join books
  on grp.g = case when book_status_fk > 4 then '>4' else '<=4' end
group by grp.g
```